# Visual Studio 2008 custom class item template, $safeprojectname$ not reconciling

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, templates

Just setting up some quick class and object item templates and all is working great so far, but one thing I'm stuck on is the `$safeprojectname$` template parameter.

I've added this as part of the namespace portion and the `$registeredorganization$` is working fine

```
namespace $registeredorganization$.$safeprojectname$
{
    public class $safeitemname$
    {
        public $safeitemname$() 
        {
            //default constructor
        }
    }   
}
```

And I've gone into the .vstemplate file and made sure `ReplaceParameters="true"` so the only thing I guessed at this point is the period between the company and project name, so I tested this out and just for laughs removed the period, still no go. Anyone have any insight as to why this isn't working?

**EDIT**: I'll accept Jared's answer as it answers my core question "why isn't it working?" but I am adding this follow up to show how I got my desired result. Instead of using the `$safeprojectname$` or `$projectname$` I found that using **$rootnamespace$**

```
namespace $registeredorganization$.$rootnamespace$
```

or depending on how your project is named:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
```

works as I had wanted, just added this for anyone else who may come across this issue.

Comment: $rootnamespace$ worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @RDV Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$safeprojectname$` template replacement macro is only available from the New Project Dialog.  It will not work for anything added as in individual item.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The irritating thing is that in the same document you linked, they also show examples of:
`namespace $safeprojectname$`